# Is there anyway to test a vpn server connection without remote hardware?

Tags: vpn

I'm setting up a vpn server, and the test client can't connect.

I would like to know if there is a way to remotely test a vpn server, perhaps a free online service?

Comment: 1. More details needed. 2. You are testing it... with the VPN client... and it's failing. 3. Do you mean that you're looking for a way to validate that you've got the VPN server set up correctly?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have almost any type of smart phone (iPhone, Android, etc) you can set up a VPN connection from it to test it out.